# Is it possible to disable new version checking in pgAdmin 4?

Tags: pgadmin-4

New versions of pgAdmin 4 are being released every month, and it's so annoying to see a popup with notification about another update. There's no option in preferences to disable it. Is there a trick to disable this particular popup, except installing the new version?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add this line to `config_local.py` and restart the pgadmin4:

```
UPGRADE_CHECK_ENABLED=False
```

**Note:**
The location of `config_local.py` is same as `config.py`. You can find the location of `config.py` with this command in linux:

```
$ find / -wholename "*/web/config.py" 2>/dev/null
```

If the `config_local.py` file doesn't exist yet, you can create one.

Comment: The solution works! The only note is that, as I work on Mac, my config is stored in `/Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/web/config_local.py`

Comment: On windows as well. Whereever the  pgAdmin4.exe file is in the folder above that is a folder called "web" and there it is

Comment: On Linux I found `~/.config/pgadmin4/config_local.py` works.

Answer (score 6):

In Windows you can change this value directly in the config.py file found in:
`%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\version\pgAdmin 4\web\`

(where `version` is your PG version)

Or in later pgAdmin:
`%ProgramFiles%\pgAdmin 4\v6\web`

(where `v6` is a sub-version of pgAdmin)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the *dpage/pgadmin4* Docker image, adding an environment variable disabled the *check* and *notification*.

> PGADMIN_CONFIG_UPGRADE_CHECK_ENABLED=False

PGADMIN_CONFIG_ is further documented at:

https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html

Answer (score 0):

It's even possible to turn off the irritating warning message *"You have connected to a Server version that is older than is supported by pgAdmin. This may cause pgAdmin to break in strange and unpredictable ways. Or a plague of frogs. Either way, you have been warned!"*, but it's somewhat dirty (*pgadmin4-server-6.9-1.el8.x86_64.rpm + pgadmin4-web-6.9-1.el8.noarch.rpm* on RHEL v8.8):

1. `$ sudo cp /usr/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/static/js/generated/browser_nodes.js /usr/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/static/js/generated/browser_nodes.js`
2. `$ sudo vi /usr/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/static/js/generated/browser_nodes.js`
3. Type `/n.version<90500`, press `Enter`, change the found line to `1==2`, press `Esc`, and `:x` (to save and quit 'vi').

This will result in omitting the warning message unless `1==2`, which is presumably - never.

**IMPORTANT**: Clear your browser cache if the warning message persists.

Comment: While possibly correct, please explain why (in your answer) so readers understand that it will work, without having to try it